# Conditionally show fields viewing a node (not in the node add form)

Tags: 6

I know conditional fields can be use to create CCK optional fields, but I need something similar to display part of a node, according to user decisions.

I will have a question "do you like cats?", then the user will be shown another question according to what they answer to the first one, and so on.

I was thinking to create this all in one node

- field1 -> answer 'yes' -> show field2,
- field1 -> answer 'no' -> show field3),

but I guess this could be done the same with multiple nodes

- node1 -> answer 'yes' -> show node2,
- node1 -> answer 'no' -> show node3.

Do you have any module to suggest me to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved this yet, the [Webform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module might help.

> This modules enhances the existing Conditional Rules of the Webform Module. It adds the ability to make components dependent on select components(i.e. listboxes, radio buttons, and checkboxes) that appear on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. This works with CCK in Drupal 6 and the [States API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

With the example given I guess taxonomy can be used to tag nodes and then later on filter them on basis of tagged term.So using views to list your nodes and exposing the taxonomy terms as exposed filter might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

[Field Formatter Conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc) should work for you. I use it all the time for cases like this. On the "Manage Display" tab for each field in a view mode, you can determine to either show or hide a field based on another field's value. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module, combined with [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields).